# как выполнить поиск элемента

Tags: javascript

Как в js выполнить поиск элемента? у меня в переменную занесена вот эта ссылка `<a href="тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка на элемент">`, мне нужно отсеять 'тут-какой-то-алиас' то есть весь текст который находится до якоря

Comment: Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. Вам нужно найти элемент ссылки на странице по части атрибута `href` после `#`?

Comment: мне уже проще нужно, отсеять всё до # а после # оставить

Comment: я попробовал так var href = $(this).attr("href")
  var world = href.substring('39', "100"),   но так как алиасы разные по длинны символов, то не подходит

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка на элемент" id="abc">Text</a>

var a = getElementById("abc").value;//поиск по id и получение значения

console.log(a);//вывод
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, возможны, например, такие варианты:

```js
const href = "тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка на элемент";

console.log(href.replace(/.+(?=#)/, ''));
console.log(href.match(/#.+/)[0]);
console.log(href.split(/(?=#)/)[1]);
console.log(href.slice(href.indexOf('#')));
console.log(href.slice(href.search(/#/)));
```

Но можно и проще:

```js
const a =  document.querySelector('a');

console.log(a.hash);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/#foo"></a>
```

Comment: ваш вариант хороший, но везде удаляется якорь

Comment: Если нужно сохранить #, тогда ещё проще — исправил варианты и добавил ещё один более естественный.